# How to make program wait for asynchronous NSURLConnection to finish before proceeding with next command?

Tags: ios, web-services

How can I make my program wait for an asynchronous NSURLConnection to finish before going to the next line of code?

```
SetDelegate *sjd= [SetDelegate alloc];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:post delegate:sjd];
[connection start];
```

This is how I start the connection and I handle the data received in the delegate but I want to wait for the connection to end before proceeding mainly because this is in a for loop and it has to run for each element in my database.

I need to put data from the phones database to a remote database and after the data was successfully put in the data in the phones database is deleted. I am going through each element in the phone's database and start a connection that's why I don't see how the next stuff can be done from the loop. I'm a beginner when it comes to objective-c programming so I'm not sure if this is the right way or not to do it

Making the call synchronous is not an option because it blocks the program and i have a progress bar that should show.

Comment: Any reason why you can't simply do that "next" stuff from the delegate instead of right there in the loop? :)

Comment: Is the purpose to avoid starting many requests in paralel? If so, your delegate method could be responsible for fetching the next result from the server. There is very few situations where you really want to block on a HTTP-request, especially if you are doing many of them.

Comment: I ran into the same situation as the OP, where I had an app that heavily used synchronous calls on a background thread, and now wanted to support custom authentication (using NSURLConnection's delegate methods), which mandates asynchronous usage. Rather the re-write the app, I could "wrap" the asynchronous calls to basically make them synchronous, since they already happen on a background thread, everything is good.

Comment: Unrelated, but this connection is getting started twice. You do not need to call `start` here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question is a bit odd. You have impossibly constrained the issue. You cannot have a line of code "wait" for a process to finish w/o it blocking something, in this case whatever thread the loop is running in.

You can use a synchronous call if you wanted to, it doesn't block your app, it only blocks the thread it is executed on. In your example, you have a loop that is continually getting remote data and you want your UI to reflect that until it is done. But you don't want your UI blocked. That means, this thread with your loop already MUST be on a background thread so you can feel free to do a synchronous call in the loop w/o blocking your UI thread. If the loop is on the UI thread you need to change this to do what you want.

You could also do this using an asynchronous connection. In that case, your operation may actual complete faster b/c you can have multiple requests in progress at the same time. If you do it that way, your loop can remain on the UI thread and you just need to track all of the connections so that when they are finished you can communicate that status to the relevant controllers. You'll need iVars to track the loading state and use either a protocol or NSNotification to communicate when loading is done.

EDIT: ADDED EXAMPLE OF SYNCHRONOUS CALL ON BACKGROUND THREAD

If you want the loop to finish completely only when all requests are finishes and not block your UI thread here's a simple example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // post an NSNotification that loading has started
    for (x = 0; x < numberOfRequests; x++) {
        // create the NSURLRequest for this loop iteration
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:&response
                                                         error:&error];
        // do something with the data, response, error, etc
    }
    // post an NSNotification that loading is finished
});
```

Whatever objects need to show loading status should observe and handle the notifications you post here. The loop will churn through and make all your requests synchronously on a background thread and your UI thread will be unblocked and responsive. This isn't the only way to do this, and in fact, I would do it using async connections myself, but this is a simple example of how to get what you want.

Comment: @pillblast, the way all apps do what you're trying to do (download something and have UI be responsive and reflect status before, during, and after) is by keeping the UI thread unblocked and doing loading operations asynchronously. You can do that either by using an asynchronous NSURLConnection or by my example above which does a synchronous request on a background thread. There is no such thing as a synchronous operation on the main (UI) thread that does not block the thread.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry I couldn't choose it as answer before the bounty ended but it intersected with the Christmas holliday. I did it using a background thread as you suggested and it works exactly as I want to. I'm just disabling the tab controller while the action takes place and everything is fine.

Comment: You should use the suggestion below instead of blocking the UI until the networking has completed. If you use notifications like jerry suggests, your UI isn't blocked and only updates once the networking connections finishes.

Comment: @anders - just saw your comment. if you read my answer, it doesn't block the UI thread and it does recommend using notifications. there are multiple ways to implement this functionality that are equally "correct".

Comment: Just one stupid consideration..Be careful with the for.  The correct syntax is for(initialization;condition;increment)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to know when it's complete and don't really care about any data, simply use the `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification and have your view subscribe to it.

**Delegate** - Post Notification upon completion

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NSURLConnectionDidFinish" object:nil];
}
```

**View** - Add observer and run some code when observed

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(yourCleanupMethod)
                                               name:@"NSURLConnectionDidFinish"
                                              object:nil];
}

-(void) yourCleanupMethod {
    // finish up

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Now, if you need to pass a simple object back as data you can try loading up the object parameter in your notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NSURLConnectionDidFinish" object:yourDataObject];
```

Then change your view and cleanup signature like this:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

// Notice the addition to yourCleanupMethod
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(yourCleanupMethod:)
                                               name:@"NSURLConnectionDidFinish"
                                              object:nil];
}

-(void) yourCleanupMethod:(NSNotification *)notif {
    // finish up
    id yourDataObject = [notif object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Now I found myself needing something a little more than this so I ended up creating a singleton to handle all of my requests.  Since all of your delegate methods in `NSURLConnectionDelegate` give you and instance of the `NSURLConnection` for the specific connection, you can simply store a mutable data object in a dictionary and look it up each time by the connection.  From there I have a method signature that takes and object and selector in that I associate with the connection so after everything has wrapped up, I can pass that mutable data object to the requestor by performing the selector on that object.

I won't include all of that code here but maybe that will help get you thinking about what is possible.  I found that I had a lot of code tied up in making web service calls so wrapping everything up in a singleton gave me a nice clean way of getting data.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Notifications are very helpful for creating "call backs" when events occur. I would suggest this method

Answer (score 3):

If you really want it to wait, why use an asynchronous call at all?  Use a synchronous call instead:

```
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil]
```

This approach will block the thread it's executed, so you should be sure you want to do it!  Did I mention that it will block?  :)

Comment: Well, that's why I don't want to use a synchronous call, because it will block the application. That is not an option.

Comment: So you want to have a series of downloads occurring, have a progress indicator, and allow the user to be doing other things, correct?  One possible avenue is to take this whole operation and put it into NSOperation.  Are you should the progress bar to show the progress of each individual download, or the set of downloads?  How many items are you downloading and how large are they?

Comment: They are not very large but they might be hundreds of them. The issue is that even in an NSOperation I would have the same issue that I am having now with using the asynchronous NSURlConnection inside the for loop.

Comment: No, the idea would be to put each request inside of it's own NSOperation, allow the NSOperation's to execute off the main thread (that's the default), and use sendSynchronousRequest.  I use this approach in my app, although I was nervous about having 100s of queued operations, so I architected it so that when it can, I put an NSArray of about 25 URL strings in an operation.  Works great.  The other general approach would be a block-based approach, which a blogger describes here: http://blog.logichigh.com/2010/09/12/cocoa-blocks/

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to wait for an **asynchronous** call to complete, so I'm assuming you're calling the code you posted up in a separate thread.

I would recommend having a look at the new `sendAsynchronourRequest` method. I've [posted up an example of how you can wrap this up in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541294/1089059) which would inform its delegate when the connection has completed / timed out / failed. I'm only referring you to this post because it sounds like you're trying to achieve something very similar to what I was at the time, and this `DownloadWrapper` class worked flawlessly for me. It's new in iOS5, mind you.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://gist.github.com/norio-nomura/62940) golden nugget helped me!
I was using synchronous NSURL just fine until I decided I needed SSL for my connection between my client and my server. I took the approach of [key pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) which is comparing the cert on the device to the cert on the server (read more on link above) and in order for it to work I needed to add code to the NSURL methods, which from my research you can't do with NSURL synchronous.
Until I found this ridiculously simple solution which worked for me:

```
NSString *connectionRunLoopMode = @"connectionRunLoopMode";
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:urlConnectionDelegate startImmediately:NO];
NSRunLoop *currentRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[connection unscheduleFromRunLoop:currentRunLoop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:currentRunLoop forMode:connectionRunLoopMode];
[connection start];
while ([currentRunLoop runMode:connectionRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
```

Comment: the while line throws a sigabrt error when I run this

Comment: @Aaron read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072135/how-to-track-down-cause-of-sigabrt

Comment: I ended up shortening this code to `NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:urlConnectionDelegate];
while (urlConnectionDelegate.flag == 0)
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];`
This allowed me to turn my synchronous call (on a background thread) into an asynchronous call supporting the authentication delegate methods while still being synchronous so as not to heavily change my app.

Answer (score -1):

NSURLConnection is already asynchronous. Simply implement the delegate methods. If you want to update the UI on the MainThread (e.g. a progress bar), you can do so in `didReceiveData.`
or look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/URLCache/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: My question was about making it synchronous practically so I don't understand your answer