# Cancel NSURLConnection started with sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:?

Tags: nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate, sendasynchronousrequest

1. Is it possible to cancel an `NSURLConnection` started with `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`?
2. Why doesn't `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` return the `NSURLConnection` object it creates so that I can cancel it?

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT - Since my provided answer seems to have been wrong, you should check out the following related question and its answers:**

### [How can I cancel an asynchronous call through NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072893/how-can-i-cancel-an-asynchronous-call-through-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousre)

**Old answer:**

In your header of your class (e.g. ViewController), declare an operation queue:

```
NSOperationQueue *downloadOperationQueue;
```

To download a file call something like the following:

```
downloadOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *fileRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo114.png"]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:10];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:fileRequest
                                   queue:downloadOperationQueue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"download successful");
                       }];
```

To cancel the download later on call:

```
[downloadOperationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Comment: According to the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html): "...queue: The operation queue to which the handler block is dispatched when the request completes or failed". ie: the queue paramater is the queue that handles the completion block, not the queue that takes care of the request itself

Comment: WTF? it will not cancel the request :D

Comment: Yes. That's why I edited the answer and provided a link to another answer.

Comment: Yes, the old answer just set isCancelled to Yes and you need to manually check and behave accordingly :/