# How to close NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue  
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {}
```

How do I close `NSURLConnection` if I use `sendAsynchronousRequest` like that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following method if you have `NSURLConnection` object

```
[conn cancel];
```

Where conn is the `NSURLConnection` object.

cancel is use to cancel asynchronous load of a request.

But in your case you dont have the object of connection so Please have a look

[How can I cancel an asynchronous call through NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072893/how-can-i-cancel-an-asynchronous-call-through-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousre)

I hope this will help you.